# SharpAdbClient.DeviceCommands.PackageManager.Install

Tags: c#, adb

I program a tool that tries to use SharpAdbClient in C # to install several APKs on several devices. But now I have a problem. I get an exception if I want to install the APKs. It works correctly if I connect only one device to the computer. Thanks in advance:

```
private DeviceData _deviceData;
private Configuration _configuration;

private string _folderPath;

public SetUp(DeviceData deviceData, Configuration configuration)
    {
        this._deviceData = deviceData;
        this._configuration = configuration;

        this._folderPath = @"..\..\File\App\";

        StartSetUp();
    }

private void StartSetUp()
{
    foreach (ConfigurationAPK configurationAPK in this._configuration.ConfigurationAPKs)
    {
        if (configurationAPK.ConfigurationMode.ID == 1)
        {
            this.Install(configurationAPK.APK);
        }
        else if (configurationAPK.ConfigurationMode.ID == 2)
        {
            this.Uninstall(configurationAPK.APK);
        }
    }
}

public void Install(APK apk)
{
    try
    {
        PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(this._deviceData, true);
        packageManager.InstallPackage(this._folderPath + apk.PackageFileName, true);    
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
    }
}

public void Uninstall(APK apk)
{
    try
    {
        PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(this._deviceData);
        packageManager.UninstallPackage(apk.PackagePath);
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(this._deviceData, true);           SharpAdbClient.Exceptions.AdbException: 'An error occurred while reading a response from ADB: more than one device'

Answer (score 0):

and now I know it. ADB tries with the serial number to install the APKs on the phones. We have to use the transport_ID instead. So if someone wants to use SharpAdbClient, library must be manipulated.

Comment: ADB start-server
ADB -t (TRANSPORT_ID) install -r App.apk    => USE TO TRANSPORT_ID FOR MORE THAN ONE DEVICE
ADB -s (SERIALNUMBER) install -r App.apk   => USE TO SRIALNUMBER FOR ONE DEVICE